# how read HTTP GET variables in javascripts?

Tags: javascript, html

I wanna know is this possible I pass get parameters for a javascript file and use them in codes?
I have this in html:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/javafile.js?q=somtext"></script>
```

know how I use this **"q"** parameter in my script codes? is this possible?

Comment: yes it seems it is dublicated :P

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can either:

1. Generate the JS dynamically with a server side language and read the query string there
2. Assume that the JS is the last `<script>` element so far in the DOM and parse `document.scripts[document.scripts.length - 1].src`

Note that if the script element has been added dynamically (i.e. with JS), it might not be the last script in the DOM.

Comment: thanks a lot. I seen in firebug that every javascript file in request send with a "_" parameter that have a a time-stamp. what do this parameter?

Comment: @IVIR3zaM — That isn't standard. Something is probably adding it as a cache buster.

Answer (score 1):

I think Quentin's suggestion is the answer to your question.

I usually use an alternative way for this, which may also help you:

Make sure that your javascript is written in a library form, and make sure that you have an instantiate method/function inside your javascript that allows you to pass parameters (or better, as an object)

```
// on dom load:
library.init({ var1: value1, var2: value2});
```

This allows you also to load your javascript in a different way, and allows for cleaner code.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can use option 3: use a library that has this functionality, e.g. MooTools: http://mootools.net/docs/more/Types/String.QueryString

Comment: It looks like it's just an utility function for `string` -> `object` conversion; you'd still have to obtain the actual path with the values first.